# JSON.parse() fail to parse a String with a JSON Object inside

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a JSON Object which contains the following structure:

> {"msg":"text","id":integer}

The user enters the text and the object is generated in the **server-side** (Java) and then passed **as a String** to JSON.parse() on the client-side.

The problem is, when a user enters a JSON Object format as the text, the function fails with:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 1

The string that resulted this error is:

> {"msg":"{ENABLE:0,MOVING:0,ERRMESSAGE:}","id":999}

Any ideas for a workaround? I don't understand why it's failing.

Comment: And the `ERRMESSAGE` field has no value, which also makes the JSON invalid.
try `{"msg":{"ENABLE": 0, "MOVING": 0, "ERRMESSAGE": null},"id":999}`
or
`{"msg":{"ENABLE": 0, "MOVING": 0},"id":999}`

Comment: That's the problem, the object inside "msg" is actually a String given by the user. So if the user types "hello", the JSON String to parse is {"msg":"hello",...}. But if the user types '{"ENABLE":0}' as the text, the JSON string that's created looks like on my original post, and JS can't parse it.

Comment: @techfoobar can you please elaborate why `"{ENABLE:0,MOVING:0,ERRMESSAGE:}"` isn't a valid JSON value? It is only a string with no inner double quotes, so no need to escape anything here. It should be valid this way

Comment: It works perfectly well when entered in Chrome console btw

Comment: @OmriSoudry can you please clarify if you run JSON.parse on the full JSON string or only on the inner part `"{ENABLE:0,MOVING:0,ERRMESSAGE:}"`

Comment: That json is valid, but you're trying to parse `json.msg` which is not.

Comment: @devnull69 I run it on the full string, then after getting the inner JSON object I run it on it.

Comment: @devnull69 - Ahh.. You're right. I didn't realise it is part of user input.

Comment: @OmriSoudry - You can run it only on the full string. The inner part cannot be reliably expected to hold valid JSON since it comes from the user.